# Value disappears from input field after I click elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, autofill

My javascript code gets injected into an iframe where it sets the value of an input field. That works great, but when I click elsewhere the value disappears from the input field.

I think that there is a variable that updates the value of the input field and this variable only updates if a user inputs something.

Is there a way so that it thinks that the user typed in the value.

EDIT: So the site that I am testing it on is not mine. I am making a chrome extension that put my javascript code in the iframe where the form is located.

this is my code:

```
element.value = "value";
```

So basically it is just setting value of the input field.
And this works perfectly because I can see the value in it, but If I click elsewhere or in the input field it disappears.

This is the site where I tested it: https://www.djangoproject.com/fundraising/

Comment: You seem to be assuming that browsers automatically remove user data from iframes and, as far as I know, they don't. In 99.9% of software issues the problem is typically in your own code. Please edit the question and provide e.g. a runnable snippet (`<>` toolbar button) that exhibits the issue.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I think you didn't understand my question. I'll edit it to make it more obvious what I am asking.